# oracle 40039 - cannot attach library ofg4tel while opening form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am trying to run a form in oracle 6i . all library files have been attached . but when i run it i keep getting  " oracle 40039 - cannot attach library ofg4tel while opening form "formname"  " . 
I have changed the path too in shortcut .

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your lib is in your FORMS90_PATH. Where you get this error even if the path is set correctly if there are other files (even subdirectories) by the same name as the library in the path. For , you may have yourlib.olb or a yourlib subdirectory. You can rename yourlib.pll to yourlib2.pll (or anything different from the original name), then detach and reattach it to your form.